# Получение отрезка символов в строке через регулярные выражения

Tags: python-3.x, re

Есть строки, к примеру:

```
a_god_by_berserk_0bllz.jpg
dream by FutureMan on ArtStation.png
a little old bymer.jpg
deathmatch by trixter.jpg
_ariel_santama__by_recphoto_fullview.jpg (1200×1860).jpg
4_new_photo_by_easypro.png
```

Нужно из всей этой мешанины вытащить всё то что содержит by(пробел либо земля) строка идущая до нижнего подчёркивания,точки или пробела.
Как итог, из приведённого примера нужно вытащить: by_berserk, by FutureMan, by trixter, by_recphoto, by_easypro.
Пробовал следующей регуляркой:

```
by( |_) *(\S|^_|^\.)*
```

Однако в любом случае, у меня выделяет диапазон либо от by до пробела, либо до конца строки, игнорируя последующие _ и .
Последующие мофидирования регулярки вроде:

```
by( |_) *(?:\S|^_|^\.)*
by( |_) *(\S*|^_*|^\.)
```

ни к чему не приводят, всё остаётся так же.
Так же интересно почему в начале регулярки в месте by( |*) *, без пробела до * выделяет только не только by* но и слова которые начинаются с by. С пробелом поиск c by и by_. Как пробел решает поведение шаблона - мне не понятно. Ведь по сути я даю шаблон: Ищи с сочетания символов by, затем должно следовать либо пробел, либо подчёркивание, а затем любое количество символов.
Помогите с реализацией. Начал изучение регулярок и что-то как то уже не охото.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/3rrjm0/1

Comment: Благодраю! Буду сидеть расшифровывать как это работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

strings = """
a_god_by_berserk_0bllz.jpg
dream by FutureMan on ArtStation.png
a little old bymer.jpg
deathmatch by trixter.jpg
_ariel_santama__by_recphoto_fullview.jpg (1200×1860).jpg
4_new_photo_by_easypro.png
"""

result = re.findall(r"(?:(?<=_)|\b)by[_\s].+?(?=\b|_)", strings)
print(result)
```

Результат:

```
['by_berserk', 'by FutureMan', 'by trixter', 'by_recphoto', 'by_easypro']
```

---

Расшифровка:

- `(?:(?<=_)|\b)` - Проверка, что слева либо символ подчёркивания, либо граница слова. Причём подчёркивание проверяется методом *"просмотра назад*" `(?<=...)` - таким образом он не попадёт в результат. И используются группировки без создания группы `(?:...)`, т.к. они нужны только в выражении, но в результате нам не интересны.
- `[_\s]` - Символ подчёркивания или пробельный символ.
- `.+?` - Любой символ в количестве больше нуля, но по-минимуму.
- `(?=\b|_)` - Граница слова или символ подчёркивания. Опять же методом *"просмотра вперёд"* `(?=...)`, чтобы в результат не попало.

Если сразу нужны только имена (без слова *by*), то достаточно будет поставить круглые скобки вокруг `.+?`, т.е. написать так: `(.+?)`

Comment: Благодарю! Вы мне очень помогли.